# Play Frame work 2.2 How Concurrent execution works

Tags: playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

Recently, we started to work with `play 2.2`. Previously we were working with play `2.1.3`.
In `play 2.2` it says `Akka.future` and async methods are seen as deprecated. Also when we tried to run below piece of code `fetchSample()` through a loop, it took more time to complete in `play 2.2`.

So how can we replace the below deprecated code with the latest one?

```
private static Promise<SampleDBResponseBean> fetchSample(
        final Document sampleDoc) throws Exception {

    Promise<SampleBean> promiseOfSampleJson = Akka.future(

    new Callable<SampleBean>() {

        public SampleBean call() throws Exception

        {
            return doSomeCalc(sampleDoc);
        }
    });
}

private Result getAsyncResult(final SampleResponseBean sampleDbResponseBean) {

    List<F.Promise<? extends SampleDBResponseBean>> promiseList = sampleDbResponseBean
            .getSampleHelperList();

    Promise<List<SampleDBResponseBean>> promiseJsonObjLists = Promise
            .sequence(promiseList);

    return async(

    promiseJsonObjLists.map(

    new Function<List<SampleDBResponseBean>, Result>() {

        public Result apply(List<SampleDBResponseBean> sampleList) {

            SampleResponseBean sampleResponseBean = new SampleResponseBean();

            sampleResponseBean.setStatus("success");

            sampleResponseBean.setSampleList(sampleList);

            JsonNode jsNodeResponse = Json.toJson(sampleResponseBean);

            return ok(jsNodeResponse);
        }
    }));
}
```

I had searched a lot of places not seeing any solution. The problem effects our code performance when comparing to `2.1.3`.

Any ideas how can we implement the deprecated methods for the above 2 methods in `play 2.2`?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the migration docs:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22

You want to use `Promise.promise`.  This is also described in the documentation:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAsync

And of course in the API docs:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#promise(play.libs.F.Function0)

One of the really nice things about Play 2.2 Java promises is now you can control exactly which execution context the code runs in, so you can create your own execution context, or get one from Akka, and so control exactly how many, in your case, concurrent DB operations are run across the whole app at the same time.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. But my doubt is http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22 still they are describing about Akka.future eventhough its deprecated, so where can we get sample code for Promise.promise? My requirement is I had a loop , from the loop each time doing some calculations. each calculation will take some time. So i need to execute the calculations concurrently. If you are sharing any sample piece of code for this it will be great help for us.. Thank you

Comment: Hi James we are able to run the concurent execution and sample code is giving below The below method is calling from a loop and its executing concurrently in play 2.2....public Promise<Double> getRandom() {
  Promise<Double> random = Promise.promise(new Function0<Double>() {
   public Double apply() {
    System.out.println("apply");
    try {
     Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Math.random();
   }
  });

  return random;
 }